# Does anyone know how to create a pdf from information that a user fills out in swift ui?

Tags: templates, pdf, swiftui, generator

I made a template pdf in latex and want to be able to have the code automatically fill in the specific fields from what the user fills out in Swift UI. Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks